# How to calculate difference vector in word2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, calculation, document-classification

I have a binary word2vec file and I am using `gensim` to load it.

While there is function to get `similarity` between 2 words in gensim but no function to calculate and return difference vector.

How can I use two vectors and get there difference vector?

And also I am trying to use these difference vectors as feature in document classification.Calculating diff vector between each word and each class.Is this right approach?

For example if classes are `sport` and `politics`

```
sport = [0.4,0.456,45,...] #wordvector of class
politics = [0.23,0.56...] #wordvector of class
```

And my word is `football`

```
football = [0.2,0.6,0.45,...] #wordvector of football
```

I want to calculate diff vector

```
(sport - football) = [some vector] # this as a feature for classification
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use two vectors and get there difference vector?

Your premonition of simply subtracting two vectors seems correct (source:https://blog.galvanize.com/add-and-subtract-words-like-vectors-with-word2vec-2/). You can use tensorflow to subtract these word vectors, if I remember correctly gensim uses tf.

> And also I am trying to use these difference vectors as feature in document classification.Calculating diff vector between each word and each class.Is this right approach?

I don't know your goal, but I would look into training your own neural net, to classify words/documents, I would look at the new package flair to help you with that. https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair/issues/787

Answer (score 0):

The vectors themselves support subtraction via the normal Python `-` operator, so if your loaded word-vectors are in the variable `wv`, it really is as simple as:

```
diff_vector = wv['sport'] - wv['football']
```

You could then try to find other vectors closest to the new vector via:

```
wv.most_similar(positive=[diff_vector])
```

Because the common-case of analogy-solving requires a mixture of positive and negative vectors, the `most_similar()` method even lets you supply negative-examples, so you could also do the difference-and-most-similar in a single step:

```
wv.most_similar(positive=['sport'], negative=['football')
```

(The results might be slightly different than the 1st approach, due to some different ordering of unit-normalization that happens inside `most_similar()`.)